# How to show up the settings for text to speech in my app?

Tags: android

I have an application which uses the tts engine in Android, now as the activity starts, I want to show to the users the settings present in the phone for the tts engine in which they can change the pitch, test the engine, etc which is already present in the emulator.

So, how do I present to them this screen?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem for my app and found this post. I managed to do it by myself so this answer is for those who might need it as well.

```
ComponentName componentToLaunch = new ComponentName(
        "com.android.settings",
        "com.android.settings.TextToSpeechSettings");
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setComponent(componentToLaunch);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

We create an explicit intent, and we have to launch the com.android.settings.TextToSpeechSettings component.
You can use LogCat in eclipse to find whatever package or component you are trying to launch. Just look at the ActivityManager's Starting activity messages and you will see the package and component name of any Activity.

**UPDATE**

As of Android ICS you should use the solution that the **Force** posted below.

```
intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It seems this version doesn't work anymore (at least on Samsung note 2 (API 18)). The answer from Force works though.
'''
intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
this.startActivity(intent);'''

Comment: Thanks @Jani. I updated my answer to point to Force's solution as well.

Answer (score 25):

For ICS users Bandreid's call won't work anymore. You have to use this code:

```
intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 9):

I have merged *Bandreid's* and *Force's* answer to support every Android Version.

Use this code:

```
//Open Android Text-To-Speech Settings
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}else {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TextToSpeechSettings"));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Or in one line:

```
//Open Android Text-To-Speech Settings
startActivity(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 ?
        new Intent().setAction("com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS").setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) :
        new Intent().addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TextToSpeechSettings")).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Hope my answer help!

Answer (score 2):

Create an Intent to open the settings. I think it would be.

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(i); // to come back to your activity.
```

Comment: thanks, but this would give the user keyboard settings.I wanted to show this screen which is in Settings-> Text to Speech . Here is the screen shot : http://picasaweb.google.com/113593639172348814875/ScreenShots#5489006879503683298