# Show “Text-to-speech settings” page from application in Honeycomb?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, text-to-speech

I'd like to know what is the way to show Text-to-speech settings page in Honeycomb.

In previous Android versions using action com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS worked. Now it gives a class cast exception.

[How show “Voice Input and Output” settings page from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702790/how-show-voice-input-and-output-settings-page-from-application)

```
06-06 06:59:33.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.TextToSpeechSettings}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.settings.TextToSpeechSettings cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Comment: using com.android.settings.VOICE_INPUT_OUTPUT_SETTINGS works by opening Language and input. But is there a way to open text-to-speech settings directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a few days trying to figure it out by analyzing the [Android Settings source code on Github](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings) (at a point in the history estimated to be Honeycomb) and I just got it working a few minutes ago!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, "com.android.settings.TextToSpeechSettings");
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT_ARGUMENTS, intent.getExtras());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Using KitKat, just replace the fragment extra with "com.android.settings.tts.TextToSpeechSettings" for it to work.