# How do I open android Text to speech settings from preference screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-settings

I am trying to open the android default TTS settings whenever I click on the particular preference in my App settings. My pref_settings.xml looks like this:

```
     <PreferenceScreen
    android:key="Lang_Select"
    android:title="Language"
    android:summary="Select a Language">

</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is my list in android settings. and my SettingsActivity.java looks like this:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

}

public static class ChatSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings);


    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.finish();
}
```

}

How can I start the android default TTS settings whenever the language button is clicked?

Thanks.

Comment: usually, you can start the settings via: `startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);` . For different action types see here:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html. I guess what you need is `ACTION_VOICE_INPUT_SETTINGS` but I have not tested it....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I am new to this thing. So can you please help me out with defining the onClickListener for the preference list? Where shall I add the code to start an intent?

Comment: I tried, look at my answer....

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with PreferenceFragmentCombat only with normal PreferenceFragment, but I guess it´s not that much difference in the basic implementations. So please, be noticed that this is maybe not the answer for your problem, but I try to help you a little bit and have to show some code. I have done it in my `onCreate()` method like this:

```
public class PreferenceFragment extends android.preference.PreferenceFragment {

private Preference mYourPreference;

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_layout);

//initialize your preference with the key you used in xml layout
mYourPreference=(Preference)getPreferenceManager().findPreference(yourPreferenceKey);    

//set on click listener
mYourPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

//start the activity
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_VOICE_INPUT_SETTINGS), 0);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I don´t know if `ACTION_VOICE_INPUT_SETTINGS` will work, just try it.

Comment: @ Opiatefuchs Thanks a lot for the help. The above code solved my purpose of opening android voice settings.

Comment: I used intent.setComponent( new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.S‌​ettings$InputMethodA‌​ndLanguageSettingsAc‌​tivity" )); to open up language and input settings but for text to speech I am unable to find anything.

Comment: look what i have found, maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160447/how-to-show-up-the-settings-for-text-to-speech-in-my-app

Comment: Try "com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS" as action, working on OS >= 5

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
startActivity(Intent("com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS"))
```

See: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:cts/apps/CtsVerifier/src/com/android/cts/verifier/speech/tts/TtsTestActivity.java;l=21?q=TTS_SETTINGS